# Need to fetch latest record always and ignore if there is no latest data

Tags: t-sql

Basically i want to send mail whenever there is a new record in this table throughout the day with list of all records got created.

I have a table with one date column. i have to always fetch the latest data based on that column and it should not give nay result if there is no latest record after the last one.

For ex:- latest record pulled at 9 AM and after that there is no update then it should not pull the same data again.

Comment: So presumably you need to store the last processed date somewhere or add a column that can be used to flag rows as processed. what is your question?

Comment: @Martin:- yes data is getting stored every time any record or multiple record gets created in that table with the timestamp. I need to fetch the list of records from latest timestamp and send in the mail as these are the records created now. Later after regular interval i need to check again if anything created after last latest timestamp then need to send else no mail.

Comment: And what question do you have about this?

Comment: @Martin:- Question is how to do this ?

Comment: An example of what you have and what you want as the result would really be helpful. So far this looks like a simple query with a filter. What's the catch? What did you try and what didn't work?

Comment: @Andriy:- I have explained below in the comment and got the solution by "Fallvind" and "Mguerra Torres" and thsi is what I was looking for. So kindly move this to a valid qstn from on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at creating a trigger on the table, and having the trigger set to email the inserted rows as appropriate.

There is no point me explaining how exactly, as Aaron Bertrand gave a super answer to this premise here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10755469/send-e-mail-from-a-trigger

I have implemented this sucesfully to send email alerts when certain values change or rows are deleted. Works perfectly.

Comment: Makes sense..can you tell me how data gets stored in Trigger tables. as one row at a time or bulk. Like many rows inserted at a  time, so i can fetch all of them at one short from trigger table or i need to insert them into another table and get it ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above replies, I'd suggest making a new table (a historical log, of sorts) to track the dates processed.  Heck, you can even make the table a 1 Column (LastDateProcessed) table.
Then just reference the table when deciding to process or not.

```
DECLARE @LastDateProcessed DATETIME, @LatestDateInTable DATETIME;
SELECT @LastDateProcessed = MAX(LastDateProcessed)
FROM HistoricalTable;

SELECT @LatestDateInTable = MAX(LatestDateInTable)
FROM YourTable;

IF (@LastDateProcessed > @LatestDateInTable)
BEGIN

--RUN YOUR CODE TO PROCESS HERE
END
ELSE
BEGIN
--DO NOTHING, RETURN "Already imported this data/date" MESSAGE;
END
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Even i thought the same logic but issue is there is no historical table for this.

Comment: And you can't create one?  If not then I'd suggest altering the current table to add a PROCESSED_Y_N indicator flag column.  Then, ensuring your process marks the flag as Y as it processes.

Comment: No alteration of table is allowed as well as no new table :(

Comment: Looks like you're in a tough spot.  Given your limitations, you may want to simply send one email per day and looks for records generated in that day.  Or if the Date column in your existing table is of DATETIME/DATETIME2 datatype, you can send an email every hour/4 hours with all records that have the DateTimeStamp of the last X hours.

Comment: yes really tough spot!!! Date column in my table is of type DATETIME. I have to send mail with the list of all records as and when any set of data is pushed into this table.(Only latest)

Comment: OK, then your best option right now (aside from a trigger, which is a great option) is to send an email every hour or (x) hours which includes data returned by this query:  SELECT [DATA] FROM [TABLE] WHERE [TABLE].[DATADATETIME] > DATEADD(HOUR,-X,GETDATE())  , where X is the number of hours between emails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42499/discussion-between-puskar-and-mguerratorres).